# Confusion with malloc. Creating an array of strings with 4 slots

Tags: c, malloc

```
int main() {

  char *p[] = {"hello", "goodbye"};

  char **a;
  a = malloc(4 * 8);

}
```

I want a to have double the slots of p. How would I successfully do that without manually putting in numbers. All IK is the size of p should be there and x 2 for the double. How would I get the 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `sizeof` operator which returns you the size in bytes that a
type/variable needs.

In your case

```
int main() {

  // because "hello" and "goodbye" are const char*
  const char *p[] = {"hello", "goodbye"};

  size_t len_p = sizeof p / sizeof p[0];

  char **a;
  a = malloc( 2 * len_p * sizeof *a );

  ...


  free(a);

}
```

`sizeof p / sizeof p[0];` returns you the number of elements in the `p` array.
`sizeof p` returns you the total amount of bytes, `sizeof p[0]` returns you the
size of single element. Hence *total size / size of element* returns you the
number of elements. But be aware that this method only works for arrays, not
pointer. Consider this:

```
void add_one(int *ptr)
{
    size_t len = sizeof ptr / sizeof ptr[0];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        ptr[i] += 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2 3 };

    add_one(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

is wrong, because `ptr` is pointer, not an array, so `sizeof ptr` returns you
the size of a pointer, not the total amount of bytes needed by `arr`. That's why
when you write a function that takes a pointer where you pass an array, the
function should also take the size of the array, otherwise the size cannot be
calculated, for example:

```
void add_one(int *ptr, size_t len)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        ptr[i] += 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2 3 };

    add_one(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to figure out how many strings have been put in `p`.  To do this, you can count the number of elements in `p` :

```
char *p[] = { "hello", "goodbye" };
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p));
```

`sizeof(p)` is the total size of `p`

`sizeof(*p)` is the size of a single element of `p`

so dividing them gives you the number of elements in `p`

To `malloc()` a second array, twice as large :

```
int main() {

    char *p[] = { "hello", "goodbye", "lala" };

    size_t size = sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p);

    char **a;
    a = malloc(size * 2 * sizeof(*a));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void allocarr(char** matrix, int bytes, int slots)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= slots)
    {
        matrix[i] = (char*)calloc(1, bytes);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

**...**

```
char** s = malloc(4*sizeof(char*);
s = allocarr(s, 512, 4);
```